# Function Looping Over Multiple Dataframes to Create New Categorical Data Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new category column from two different Pandas dataframes that contain the same columns using Pandas.

The new column looks at both Df1 and Df2's 'Loan Code/Number' column, determines if they're the same then determines if the 'Del_Cat' category changed from Df1 to Df2, and if it changed categories, it will return a new result.

DF1:

| Loan Code/Number | Days Delinquent | Del_Cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1147623994 | -25 | Current |
| 1501719058 | -5 | Current |
| 1501719696 | 77 | 61-90 |
| 1502624989 | 87 | 61-90 |
| 1502625152 | 16 | Current |

DF2:

| Loan Code/Number | Days Delinquent | Del_Cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1147623994 | -22 | Current |
| 1801719152 | 37 | 31-60 |
| 1501719696 | 84 | 61-90 |
| 1602624414 | -6 | Current |
| 1502625152 | 55 | 31-60 |

I've tried creating a function that loops over the values in the tables and determines if the loan number is the same, and if it is then to check the values in the 'Del_Cat' column, bringing back a new value that states if the value has changed:

```
def del_cat_migration(df1, df2): 
    if [df1['Loan Code/Number'] == df2['Loan Code/Number']]:
        if (df1['Del_Cat']) == 'Current' & (df2['Del_Cat']) == 'Current':
            return 'Same - Current'
        elif (df1['Del_Cat']) == 'Current' & (df2['Del_Cat']) == '31-60':
            return 'Current to 31-60'
        elif (df1['Del_Cat']) == '31-60' & (df2['Del_Cat']) == '31-60':
            return 'Same - 31-60'
        elif (df1['Del_Cat']) == '31-60' & (df2['Del_Cat']) == '61-90':
            return '31-60 to 61-90'
        elif (df1['Del_Cat']) == '61-90' & (df2['Del_Cat']) == '61-90':
            return 'Same - 61-90'
        elif (df1['Del_Cat']) == '61-90' & (df2['Del_Cat']) == 'Current':
            return '61-90 to Current'
        else:
            return 'Other'
```

I then try to apply this new data to a new column in df2:

```
df2['Del_Migration_Cat'] = df2.apply(del_cat_migration(df1, df2), axis = 1)
```

I then get the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

These are the dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Loan Code/Number":[1147623994, 1501719058, 1501719696, 1502624989, 1502625152],
                   "Days Delinquent":[-25,-5,77,87,16],
                   "Del_Cat":["Current","Current","61-90","61-90","Current"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Loan Code/Number":[1147623994, 1801719152, 1501719696, 1602624414, 1502625152],
                   "Days Delinquent":[-22,37,84,-6,55],
                   "Del_Cat":["Current","31-60","61-90","Current","31-60"]})
```

Comment: The error is caused by missing/wrong parentheses (see [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), pay attention to the parentheses), but in general, your approach won't get you very far: you can't manually spell out all possible combinations. See my answer below for a more canonical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's ways to do such things in pandas:

```py
def del_cat_migration(row):
    if row[0] == row[1]:
        return f"Same - {row[0]}"
    
    return f"{row[0]} to {row[1]}"

df3 = pd.concat([df1["Del_Cat"], df2["Del_Cat"]], axis=1)
```

`df3` looks like

```py
   Del_Cat  Del_Cat
0  Current  Current
1  Current    31-60
2    61-90    61-90
3    61-90  Current
4  Current    31-60
```

Now apply the function, row-wise (`axis=1`):

```py
>>> df3.apply(del_cat_migration, axis=1)
0      Same - Current
1    Current to 31-60
2        Same - 61-90
3    61-90 to Current
4    Current to 31-60
```

Answer (score 1):

**The cause:** you cannot do the comparison in if statement between two columns of a dataframe because the result of this comparison is a boolean series [True, False, ....]  which is invalid condition, therefore, you should use `a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()` as indicated by the error log. The suggested option is invalid because you need only to compare between each entry in `df1` and the corresponding entry in `df2`. I fixed this issue as in the solution below and also correct some syntax errors in the function.

But again, your function will have a problem with df2.apply() will iterate through each row and call the function in each row with the entire dataframes which is not valid operation, as well.

```
def del_cat_migration(df1, df2):
    bool_index = (df1['Loan Code/Number'] == df2['Loan Code/Number'])
    
    for i in df1.index[bool_index]:
        if (df1.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == 'Current') & (df2.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == 'Current'):
        df2.loc[i,'Del_Migration_Cat'] = 'Same - Current'
    elif (df1.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == 'Current') & (df2.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == '31-60'):
        df2.loc[i,'Del_Migration_Cat'] = 'Current to 31-60'
    elif (df1.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == '31-60') & (df2.loc[i,'Del_Cat']  == '31-60'):
        df2.loc[i,'Del_Migration_Cat'] = 'Same - 31-60'
    elif (df1.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == '31-60') & (df2.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == '61-90'):
        df2.loc[i,'Del_Migration_Cat'] = '31-60 to 61-90'
    elif (df1.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == '61-90') & (df2.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == '61-90'):
        df2.loc[i,'Del_Migration_Cat'] = 'Same - 61-90'
    elif (df1.loc[i,'Del_Cat'] == '61-90') & (df2.loc[i,'Del_Cat']  == 'Current'):
        df2.loc[i,'Del_Migration_Cat'] = '61-90 to Current'
    else:
        df2.loc[i,'Del_Migration_Cat'] = 'Other'

del_cat_migration(df1, df2)
```

*But I prefer to follow the answer of @fsimonjetz, however, you need for an extra dataframe df3.*

Answer (score 1):

first, let's merge df's on 'Loan Code/Number' column, then we can apply function:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Loan Code/Number','Del_Cat']], 
               on='Loan Code/Number',
               how='left',
               suffixes=(None, '_2'))
print(df3)
'''
   Loan Code/Number  Days Delinquent  Del_Cat Del_Cat_2
0        1147623994              -25  Current   Current
1        1501719058               -5  Current       NaN
2        1501719696               77    61-90     61-90
3        1502624989               87    61-90       NaN
4        1502625152               16  Current     31-60
'''
df3 = (df3.assign(Del_Cat=df3.apply(lambda x: f"same {x['Del_Cat']}" 
                                    if x['Del_Cat']==x['Del_Cat_2'] 
                                    else 'Other' if x['Del_Cat_2']!=x['Del_Cat_2']
                                    else f"{x['Del_Cat']} to {x['Del_Cat_2']}", axis=1)).
       drop(columns='Del_Cat_2'))
print(df3)
'''
   Loan Code/Number  Days Delinquent           Del_Cat
0        1147623994              -25      same Current
1        1501719058               -5             Other
2        1501719696               77        same 61-90
3        1502624989               87             Other
4        1502625152               16  Current to 31-60
```